# Does the square of a symmetric walk length have a mean?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider a symmetric random walk starting at the origin where the positions are non negative integers.  Each move goes right/left with probability 1/2 except if you are at the origin you always go right.

Let $X$ be the number of steps to get to 10. Does $X^2$ have a mean?

Comment: the initial $0$ and the change in its transitions makes it much less pleasant somehow

Comment: Is your question strictly "Does $X^2$ have a mean?" Or does it also include (implicitly): "If so, what is the mean?"

Comment: @paw88789 I would love to know what the mean is too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide time into blocks of length 10 steps. In each block, there is a chance of at least $p=2^{-10}$ that the walk will reach 10,
so the hitting time $X=\tau$ can be bounded above by $10Y$ where $Y$ is a Geometric variable with parameter $p$. Thus by [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Moments_and_cumulants),
$$E (X^2) \le 100 E(Y^2)=100(2-p)/p^2.$$
This bound is far off. To calculate $E (X^2)$, one can set up and solve a recursion. The most powerful method, which requires some preparation, is to use the optional stopping theorem for Martingales. This is a topic you can find in most probability textbooks, e.g. the books by Durrett, by Billingsley and by Williams, or in Chapter 17 of [this](https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times/).

Let $S_n$ be simple random walk on the integers, which steps left or right with equal probability, where $S_0=0$. Then the process you consider is exactly $|S_n|$, so your $X$, which I will now call $\tau$, is the time for $|S_n|$ to reach $L=10$. Let's find the moments of $\tau=X$ for any target integer $L>0$. If $|k|<L$, then  (with the subscript indicating the starting point of the simple random walk)
$$E_k(\tau)=1+\frac{E_{k-1}(\tau)+E_{k+1}(\tau)}{2}\,,$$
and $E_L(\tau)=E_{-L}(\tau)=0$ The unique solution of this recursion is
$$E_k(\tau)=L^2-k^2\,.$$
Alternatively, the standard quadratic Martingale $Q_t=S_t^2-t$ yields
$$0=E(Q_0)=E(Q_{\tau \wedge n})=E(S_{\tau \wedge n}^2)-E(({\tau \wedge n})^2)\,.
$$
Thus $$E(S_{\tau \wedge n}^2)=E(({\tau \wedge n})^2)\,.$$
Taking a limits as $n \to \infty$, using the lebesgue bounded convergence theorem on the left and monotone convergence on the right, we get
$$L^2=E(S_{\tau }^2)=E( \tau  ^2)\,.$$

To calculate the second moment,
first consider $L=2$. then $\tau=2G$ where $G$, the number of visits to zero, is Geometric$(1/2)$. Thus $E(\tau^2)=4E(G^2)=24$ for $L=2$.

For the general case, we use the process
$$M_{t}=S_t^4 - 6t S_t^2 + 3t^2 + 2t \,.
$$
It is straightforward to check that
$E(M_{t+1})|S_t)=M_t$ for every $t$, i.e., $M_t$ is a martingale. One can discover $M_t$ in a principled way, see section 17.3.3 in [2](https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times/).

Optional Stopping (the version recalled below) yields
$$
0=L^4-6E_0(\tau)L^2+3E_0(\tau^2)+2E_0(\tau)=-5L^4+3E_0(\tau^2)+2L^2
\,.
$$
Solving for $E_0(\tau^2)$ gives
$$
E_0(\tau^2)=(5L^4-2L^2)/3 \,,
$$
In particular, for $L=10$ this gives $$E(X^2)=E(\tau^2)=16,600 \,.$$

**Optional Stopping Theorem, Version 3** (Cor 17.8 p. 246 in [2](https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times/)).
Let $(M_t)$ be a martingale for some filtration,  that has
bounded increments, that is
$|M_{t+1} - M_t| \leq B$ for all $t$  where $B$ is a non-random
constant.  Suppose that $\tau$ is a stopping time for the same filtration,
with
$ E(\tau) < \infty$.  Then $ E(M_{\tau}) =  E(M_0)$.

https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf

Comment: Thank you! This is very educational too.

Comment: And thanks to @Youem for editing